# Override controller's path in routes possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for an advice how to override controller's path by some suitable matching rule in Rails::Engine in routes.rb.

I'd like to replace

```
/stub/category/
```

with

```
/category/
```

Tried something like

```
Rails::Engine.routes.prepend do
    match '/stub/category', :to => 'category#index', :as => '/category'
end
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
match 'stub/category' => 'category#index' :as => 'category'
```

Comment: First it's a syntax error because missing colon before :as. Second it does not override the path. After rails restart the old 'stub/category' path remains untouched.